# Creating an auxiliary table to improve performance on a large MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a client who has asked me to tune his MySQL database in order to implement some new features and to improve the performance of an already existing web app.

The biggest table (~90 GB) has over 200M rows, and is growing at periodic intervals (one per visit to any of the websites he owns). Having continuous INSERTs, each SELECT query performed from the backend page takes a while to complete, as indexes are regenerated each time.

I've done a simulation on my own server switching from BTREE indexes to HASH indexes. Both SELECTs and INSERTs are not running any faster. The table uses MyISAM as storage engine. There are only INSERTs and SELECTs, no UPDATEs or DELETEs.

I've came up with the idea of creating an auxiliary table updated together with each INSERT to speed up every SELECT query coming from the backend. I know this is bad practice, but, I'm sure the performance will improve for the statistics page.

I'm not a database performance expert, as you may have noticed... Is there a better approach for this?

By the way, from phpMyAdmin I've seen that most indexes on the table have a cardinality of 0. In my simulation, this didn't happen. I'm not sure why is this happening.

Thanks a lot.

1st update: I've just learned that hash index isn't available for MyISAM engine.

2nd update: OK. Here's the table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `datetime` int(8) NOT NULL,
 `webmaster_id` char(18) NOT NULL,
 `country` char(2) NOT NULL,
 `connection` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `device` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `provider` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `user_agent` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `datetime` (`datetime`),
 KEY `webmaster_id` (`webmaster_id`),
 KEY `country` (`country`),
 KEY `connection` (`connection`),
 KEY `device` (`device`),
 KEY `provider` (`provider`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

So, instead of performing queries like `select count(*) from visits where datetime=20140715 and device="ios"`, won't it be best to fetch this from `select count from visits_stats where datetime=20140715 and device="ios"`?

INSERTs are, as said, much more frequent than SELECTs, but my client wants to improve the performance of the backend used to retrieve aggregated data. Using my approach, each visit would imply one INSERT and one INSERT/UPDATE (or REPLACE) which would increment one or more counters (I haven't decided the schema for the visits_stats table yet, the above query was just an example).

Apart from this, I've decided to replace some of the fields by their appropriate IDs from a foreign table. So far, data is stored in strings like connection=cable, device=android, and so on. I'm not sure how would this affect performance.

Thanks again.

Comment: Why don't you post the query, table & index definitions as well as the execution plan so people here can really try to help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I said before not to use partitions. But Bill is right that the way he described would work. Your only concern would be if you tried to select across the 101 partitions, then the whole thing would come to a standstill. If you don't intend to do this then partitioning would solve the problem. Fix your indexes first though.

Your primary problem is that MyISAM is not the best engine, neither is InnoDB. TokuDB would be your best bet, but you'd have to install that on the server.

Now, you need to prune your indexes. This is the major reason for the slowness. Remove an index on everything that isn't part of common `SELECT` statements. Add an multi-column index on exactly what is requested in the `WHERE` of your `SELECT` statements.

So (in addition to your primary key) you want an index on `datetime, device` only as a multi-column index, according to your posted `SELECT` statement.

If you change to TokuDB the inserts will be much faster, if you stick with MyISAM then you could speed the whole thing up by using `INSERT DELAYED` instead of `INSERT`. The only issue with this is that the inserts will not be live, but will be added whenever MySQL decides there is not too much load.

Alternatively, if the above still does not help, your final option would be to use two tables. One table that you `SELECT` from, and another that you `INSERT` to. Once an day or so you would then copy the insert table to the select table. Though this means the data in your select table could be up to 24 hours old.

Other than that you would have to completely change the table structure, for which I can't tell you how to do because it depends on what you are using it for exactly, or use something other than MySQL for this. However, my above optimizations should work.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking into partitioning. You have to add `datetime` to the primary key to make that work, because of a limitation of MySQL. The primary or unique keys must include the column by which you partition the table.

Also make the index on `datetime` into a compound index on `(datetime, device)`. This will be a *covering index* for the query you showed, so the query can get its answer from the index alone, without having to touch table rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `datetime` int(8) NOT NULL,
 `webmaster_id` char(18) NOT NULL,
 `country` char(2) NOT NULL,
 `connection` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `device` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `provider` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `user_agent` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `datetime`), -- compound primary key is necessary in this case
 KEY `datetime` (`datetime`,`device`), -- compound index for the SELECT
 KEY `webmaster_id` (`webmaster_id`),
 KEY `country` (`country`),
 KEY `connection` (`connection`),
 KEY `device` (`device`),
 KEY `provider` (`provider`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY HASH(datetime) PARTITIONS 101;
```

So when you query for `select count(*) from visits where datetime=20140715 and device='ios'`, your query is only scanning one partition, with about 1% of the rows in the table. Then within that partition, it narrows down even further using the index.

Inserts should also improve, because they are updating much smaller indexes.

I use a prime number when doing hash partitioning, to help the partitions remain more evenly filled in case the dates inserted follow a regular pattern.

Converting a 90GB table to partitioning is going to take a long time. You can use [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) to avoid blocking your application.

You can even make more partitions if you want, in theory up to 1024 in MySQL 5.5 and 8192 in MySQL 5.6. Although with thousands of partitions, you may run into different bottlenecks, like the number of open files.

P.S.: HASH indexes are not support by either MyISAM or InnoDB. HASH indexes are only supported by MEMORY and NDB storage engines.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the problem which is called Big Data Querying / Big Data handling now a days. For handling big data there are many solutions available unfortunately none of them are easy enough to be implemented. You always need a team to structure Big Data to fulfill your need. Some of The solution I may define here are as Under.
1. Big Table
 Google uses this technique to create a whole lot big table with thousands of column.(To minimize records vertically). For which you will have to analyze your data and then partition on the basis of similarity and then tag those similarity with appropriate name. Now you must have to write Query that will be first analyzed by some algorithm to check what column space have to be queried. **Not Simple enough**
2. Distribute Database Across multiple Machine
   Hadoop file system is an open source Apache project which is totally created for solving the problem of storing and querying big data. In early days Space was issue and system were capable enough to process small data but now space is not an issue.Even Small organization have tera bytes of data stored locally. But this terabytes of data can not be be processed in one go at one machine. Even a giant machine can take days to process aggregate operation. That is why hadoop is there.

**If you are individual then definitely you are in trouble you will need resource for doing this painful task for You. But you can use the essence of these techniques without employing these technologies.**
You are free to give a try to these technique. Just study articles about handling big data. Relational database queries are not gonna work in your case